# bootstrap unselectable radio button

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

i have this btn-group:

```
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Sex</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input id="filtro_sexo" type="hidden" />
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle-name="filter_sex" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                        <button value="Male" type="button" class="btn">Male</button>
                        <button value="Female" type="button" class="btn">Female</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

the problem is that I need the user to be able to select or deselect the option. the user should be able to select one option, or none.
but data-toggle = "buttons-radio" will not let me deselect the option selected.

Comment: There is any reason to do not use <input type="radio" />?

Comment: The above code will give you two buttons instead of radio buttons. For radio buttons try using `<input type="radio" name="" value""/>`

Comment: The client wants it that way because it will run on a touch environment

Answer (score 1):

I achieve this by using [data-toggle=buttons-checkbox], add a custom attribute [data-single-select], and write few lines of jQuery:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" data-single-select>
    <button class="btn">...</button>
    <button class="btn">...</button>
    <button class="btn">...</button>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("[data-toggle='buttons-checkbox'][data-single-select] .btn").live('click', function(evt){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

@Rafael
using [input type="radio"] looks way too ugly. That's why we use Bootstrap.